# API always returns onFail when getting a list of items

Tags: android

I want to get all object items from an API and put them in a ListView but I can't seem to make it work.
It always returns "Get Data Failed".

Here's my [API](http://apartmentpp.azurewebsites.net/hoangapi/rooms?apartmentId=1), I am calling to.

The number at the end is the 'apartment Id' which consists related room and depending on the Id, it will show a list of rooms.

Sample implementation:

```
private void initView() {
        RoomRepository roomRepository = new RoomRepository();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        final String apartmentId = "rooms?apartmentId=" + intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.APARTMENTID);

        roomRepository.getRoom(this, apartmentId, new CallBackData<List<Room>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(List<Room> rooms) {
                Toast.makeText(RoomListActivity.this, "Get data successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (rooms.size() == 0)
                    Toast.makeText(RoomListActivity.this, "No Room found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else
                    buildLayout(rooms);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFail(String msg) {
                Toast.makeText(RoomListActivity.this, "Get data Failed ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

My Repository class-

```
public void getRoom(Context context, String apartmentId, final CallBackData<List<Room>> callBackData){
        clientAPI clientApi = new clientAPI();
        Call<ResponseBody> serviceCall = clientApi.roomSerivce().getRoom(apartmentId);
        serviceCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                if (response != null && response.body() != null) {
                    if (response.code() == 200) {
                        try {
                            String result = response.body().string();
                            Type type = new TypeToken<List<Room>>() {
                            }.getType();
                            List<Room> roomList = new Gson().fromJson(result, type);
                            if (roomList != null) {
                                callBackData.onSuccess(roomList);
                            } else {
                                callBackData.onFail("No data");
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    callBackData.onFail("No data");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

API config

```
public RoomSerivce roomSerivce(){
        return this.getService(RoomSerivce.class, configAPI.BASE_URL);
    }

public static final String BASE_URL = "http://apartmentpp.azurewebsites.net/";

public static final String GET_APARTMENT_ROOM = "hoangapi/";

public interface RoomSerivce {
    @GET(configAPI.GET_APARTMENT_ROOM + "/{apartmentId}")
    Call<ResponseBody> getRoom(@Path("apartmentId") String apartmentId);
}
```

Comment: you are using **_http_** instead of **_https_** so there is high possibility of not getting server response because of **Network security configuration** in recent security update.. check your logcat debug and see if there is any message related to network security

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra '/' in your url which makes it wrong. Look at below mentioned lines of code:

`public static final String GET_APARTMENT_ROOM = "hoangapi/";`

It has a '/' at the end.

`@GET(configAPI.GET_APARTMENT_ROOM + "/{apartmentId}")`

It has a '/' in start.

When you concatenate them, it creates `hoangapi//room?apartmentId=`.

Double forward slash is the real cause. 
Remove the one before apartmentId and your are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Isolating the error, you can see that is between the app and the server or after the server answered.

So you need to debug the code and discovery where the onFail() is called. If is called when response is null, you need to test the connection between de app and the server. If is in the conversion of the list, you need to revise your domain and compare with the json server.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public interface RoomSerivce {
    @GET("hoangapi/rooms")
    Call<ResponseBody> getRoom(@Query("apartmentId") String apartmentId);
}
```